# Laravel 7: How to clear withErrors session

Tags: session, error-handling, permissions, laravel-7

I'm using `Gate` for permissions and redirect the user to the `home`  if he doesn't have enough permission with an error message

```
if(Gate::denies('manage-users')){
    return redirect(route('home'))->withErrors('You don\'t have enough permissions!');
}
```

But when the user navigates to another route with correct permission the page displays correctly but with an error handler in the view saying the same message "you don't have enough permissions"

How can I clear errors session once the error get displayed in `home` to hide it from other views?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the best solution so please correct me. I Changed the validation to be this

```
if(Gate::denies('manage-users')){
    return redirect(route('home'))->withErrors(['permission_error' => 'You don\'t have enough permissions!']);
    }
```

In the home view

```
@if(session()->has('permission_error'))
     {{session('errors')->get('permission_error')}}
     @php session()->forget('permission_error') @endphp
@elseif( !session()->has('permission_error') && $errors->any())
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
          {{ $errors->first() }}
     </div>
@endif
```